# How to inherit classes that inherits base class more than once

Tags: class, tcl, itcl

Title is not clear. Here I am explaining

I am having a package say `package provide test`. It is having `classes`. I am using `Itcl`. Package is having following structure

```
::itcl::class classA {
written something having constructor and methods
}

::itcl::class classB {
inherit ::test::classA
having its own constructor and methods
}

::itcl::class classC {
inherit ::test::classA
having its own constructor and methods
}

::itcl::class classD {
inehrit ::test::classB ::test::classC
having its own constructor and methods
}
```

When i am requiring `package test`, I am getting below error

```
class "::test::classD" inherits base class "::test::classA" more than once:
```

How can i handle the error

Comment: You could try switching to TclOO, which allows this sort of class structure.

Comment: @DonalFellows: As my framework is using `itcl`. I can't switch to TclOO

Answer (score 1):

Diamond inheritance is not allowed due to path ambiguity.
I.e.

```
      TopClass
      /       \
LeftClass   RightClass
      \       /
     BottomClass
```

As workaround you can use composition (has-a) rather than inheritance
(is-a).

```
::itcl::class classA {
}

::itcl::class classB {
    inherit ::test::classA
}

::itcl::class classC {
    inherit ::test::classA
}

::itcl::class classD {
   constructor {} {
     set _b [::test::classB #auto]
     set _c [::test::classC #auto]
   }
   destructor {
     ::itcl::delete $_b
     ::itcl::delete $_c
   }
   private {
      variable _b ""
      variable _c ""
   }
}
```

Now in classD you must be specific to classB or classC path the code gets to base.